# How can I use SPServices to save a "Person"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I'm attempting to save the current user to a list using SP services. The column for User is setup with the type of "Person or Group"

When I use SPServices to save it I get error code 0x80020005 which from a bit of Googling tells me that the data type is incorrect.

What format should my user name be in to allow it to be saved to a Sharepoint list with the type Person or Group?

EDIT
Below is some code with what I'm trying:

```
$().SPServices(
        {
            weburl: siteURL,
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: true,
            batchCmd: "New",
            listName: "Votes",
            valuepairs: [["Title",$_GET.storyTitle],["StoryID",parseInt($_GET.storyId)],["User","BOMEz"]],

            completefunc: function(xData,Status)
            {
            }
```

Where I have "BOMEz" in the code I've used my actual name as saved in Sharepoint by getting it with `$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName:"UserName"})`
I've also tried SipAddress and EMail all to no avail. I've also manually typed in my full name as saved in Sharepoint as well as email address, yet I keep getting the same error

Comment: You can't use SPServices to save a person, but I do think every time you use it Marc Anderson goes out and save a kitten. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting person/group fields with jQuery and SPServices, I've used account (domain\username) and email address without any issues in NewForms. Let me see if I have an example of using it in an UpdateListItems function.

If you are going to do it via web services, you need to pass in the user ID value. So you'd do something like this if you need to populate a person group field:

```
var thisUserID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "ID",
    debug: false
});

$().SPServices({
   weburl: siteURL,
   operation: "UpdateListItems",
   async: true,
   batchCmd: "New",
   listName: "Votes",
   valuepairs: [["Title",$_GET.storyTitle],["StoryID",parseInt($_GET.storyId)],["User",thisUserID]],
   completefunc: function(xData,Status){}
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, see edit in the original question.

Comment: Do you need to set the User field? The Created By field is automatically be set to the user executing the web service call.

Comment: Updated with more information.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out for me. Also good tip on just using the Created By field as well.

Comment: All Add this to Eric's answer... Using the SPGetCurrentUser() can be avoided if looking for "current user" ID... SP already sets a global variable called _spUserId with this value... This is true in SP2007 and I think in subsquent versions as well (SP2010 and 2013) - although I cant validate that on 2010/2013 right now). (also: SPGetCurrentUser() might not work in environments where heavy re-branding might have been applied... that SPSErvices Utility does a "screen scrape" thus it is vulnerable to breaking in the future).

Comment: Note that as of 2013.01, SPGetCurrentUser() attempts to get as many values for the user from existing variables as possible, so the scraping won't happen unless required.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the person(People picker) value by setting

```
 userID+";#"+Prefferedname

 var user = get_user_profile_by_login();

var userName=_spPageContextInfo.userId+";#"+user.PreferredName;

//===================================================================================
function get_user_profile_by_login(login) {
  var user = {};
  var params = {
    operation: 'GetUserProfileByName',
    async: false,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").each(function() {
        user[$(this).find("Name").text()] = $(this).find("Value").text();
      }); // end each

      user.login = user.AccountName;
      user.full_name = user.PreferredName;
      user.email = user.WorkEmail;

    } // end completefunc
  };

  if (login != null) {
    params.accountName = login;
  } else {
    params.accountName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
      fieldName: "Name"
    });
  }

  $().SPServices(params);

  return user;
}
//==========================================================================

<Field Name='Creator'>"+userName+"</Field>";
```

Let me know if you have any issue